# Angular Http POST change format value

Tags: node.js, angular

I am sending the object message to an API by using POST request on Angular :

```
//Angular

var message = {
      'title':"Test", 
      'content':"blabla", 
      'image':"none", 
      'author':"michael", 
      'likedBy':['alexis','laura']
    };

return this.http.post(this.REST_API_SERVER, message, {headers: new HttpHeaders({'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'})});
```

Actually my API output show me this :

```
OUTPUT: 
{
  '{"title":"Test","content":"blabla","image":"none","author":"michael","likedBy":': { '"alexis","laura"': '' }
}
```

But I would like this :

```
{
  _id: 5f887c43bee87a1014d89d21,
  title: 'Test',
  content: 'blabla',
  image: 'none',
  author: 'michael',
  likedBy: [ 'alexis', 'laura' ]
}
```

Comment: if you are the making the API, it must be something wrong you are doing, are you using Express ?

Answer (score 0):

You need to change content type to `application/json`.

Comment: Now I have an empty output

Comment: @Galileoomega  I am not sure what this API does?  What you mean - API output?

Comment: For now it's just a console.log(req.body)

Comment: Please try JSON.stringify(message)